# Ползунок прогресс-бара настройка

Tags: html, jquery, css

Как реализовать увеличение позиции ползунка на 20% от левого края каждый раз при нажатии кнопки "Далее", при условии, что выбран ответ?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Задавая вопрос о проблеме, источник которой вы видите в своем коде, можно рассчитывать на получение гораздо более качественных ответов, если привести код, с помощью которого участники смогут воспроизвести проблему. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve